# MongoDB aggregation pipeline doing automatic type conversion? Possible to type cast?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I created an aggregation pipeline that first `$sort`s on value descending, then `$limit`s the top *x* entries, then `$project`s some fields to the output. One of the fields, `Name`, is stored in the Collection as string (verified by querying outside of the aggregation pipeline). However, some of the strings that have only numeric characters are being converted to integers, which is problematic when my string has leading zeros.

Is there some way to cast the type before doing a query?

Is there some behavior about the aggregation pipeline that does type conversion when sorting?

Comment: Can you share the aggregation pipleline and a sample of the output?